# How to avoid refreshing and flickering while loading json with p5.js

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, p5.js

I'm trying to use p5.js to render a 3d cube on the webpage, and need to load one constantly updating JSON files to get the color features. The JSON files would be updated per second as I run a python script.

The problem is, my result web page keeps refreshing and sometimes has flickers, which is not what I wanted. How can I adjust my code so that the visual features from JSON could be rendered smoothly without any interruption? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my p5.js code below:

```
var color_data
var urls = "http://127.0.0.1:5500/data.json";
let fr = 500

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
    setInterval(loadData, 100)
    frameRate(fr);
    easycam = createEasyCam();
    document.oncontextmenu = () => false;
    easycam.setDistance(800, 0);
}

function gotData(data) {
    color_data = data
}

function loadData() {
    loadJSON(urls, gotData)
}

function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)
}

function draw() {

    function colorPart(x_value, y_value, z_value) {
        let arr = color_data[5 - y_value][5 - z_value][x_value]
        return arr.split(',')
    }

    function forRange(fn) {
        const cubeSpacing = 100
        for (let i = -250; i <= 250; i += cubeSpacing) {
            fn(i);
        }
    }

    function coordToIndex(num) {
        return (num / 50 + 5) / 2
    }

    background(155);

    translate(0, 0, -500);

    rotateY(millis() / 2000);

    // let size = Math.random() % 10 *25
    // let volume = Math.random() % 1 + 1
    let volume = 1

    forRange(x => forRange(y => forRange(z => {
        let pos = createVector(x, y, z);
        noStroke()
        push();
        translate(volume * pos.x, volume * pos.y, volume * pos.z);
        let index_x = coordToIndex(x)
        let index_y = coordToIndex(y)
        let index_z = coordToIndex(z)
        if (color_data) {
            let tem_arr = colorPart(index_x, index_y, index_z)
            fill(parseInt(tem_arr[0]), parseInt(tem_arr[1]), parseInt(tem_arr[2]));
        }
        sphere(18)
        pop();
    })))

}
```

Comment: Not very familiar with `p5` but I notice you are using `parseInt` per frame and it sounds like you only refresh JSON every second. So might want to cache the `parseInt` values to reduce overhead.

Comment: Without a fully functional sample would be hard to troubleshoot this... on that code I do not see anything that would cause a page refresh ... but in general, you should avoid doing computations on draw, can all that be done somewhere less frequently only when needed?

Comment: frameRate of 500 seems curious. Why such a high frame rate?

Comment: My initial thought is to set the framerate higher to avoid the flickering, it didn't work of course

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I meant on my comment.

I moved most of the calculations out of the draw, in setup we load the `spheres` array with the positions and an initial color then the `setInterval(changeColor, 500)` changes the color, on this case is just something random but you could do the same with data coming from a json like you are doing.

```
    colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "cyan", "white", "black", "yellow"]

    function setup() {
        spheres = []
        forRange(x => forRange(y => forRange(z => {
            color = "red"
            spheres.push({ x, y, z, color })
        })))

        createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
        frameRate(500);
        document.oncontextmenu = () => false;
        setInterval(changeColor, 500)
    }

    function changeColor() {
        spheres.forEach(obj => {
            obj.color = colors[int(random(colors.length))]
        })
    }

    function forRange(fn) {
        const cubeSpacing = 120
        for (let i = -250; i <= 250; i += cubeSpacing) {
            fn(i);
        }
    }

    function draw() {
        background(155);
        translate(0, 0, -500);
        rotateY(millis() / 2000);
        rotateX(millis() / 8000);

        spheres.forEach(obj => {
            noStroke()
            push();
            translate(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z);
            fill(obj.color)
            sphere(18)
            pop();
        })
    }
```

Here is that in action:
https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/p5_spheres.html
no-refresh and no flickers *(at least not in google chrome, I only tested there)*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I tried to modify my code with your suggestions, unfortunately, the problems still exist and somehow became worse. This time, the visual features won't even show up until the fetching is complete :(

Comment: @URlemontree like I said on my comment without a fully functional sample cant do much